# Enable htaccess error on Ubuntu 12.04 with Apache2

Tags: .htaccess, apache2

I tried to enable htaccess. I changed:

```
<Directory /var/www/abc.biz/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

To:

```
<Directory /var/www/abc.biz/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

But I'm getting 500 (Internal Server) error. Why?

Here is my `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default` file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin admin@abc.biz

DocumentRoot /var/www/abc.biz
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/abc.biz/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
LogLevel warn

CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
<Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Could we also see your `.htaccess` file? Is `mod_rewrite` enabled? Have you checked the Apache error log?

Comment: Do a <super>log and open the **Log File Viewer** then add your `/var/log/apache2/error.log` to the list of logfiles.  (Add access.log and rewrite.log if this is a dev system).  You can now inspect error logs with a GUI that you'll be comfortable with.

Comment: thankyou. i try enable mod_rewrite and get successful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need to change this part of your /etc/apache2/sites-available/default

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/abc.biz
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/abc.biz/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

to

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/abc.biz
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/abc.biz/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

Because at first `<Directory /> AllowOverride All` you allow to override settings with your .htaccess file for the whole apache, but also you need to change it at `<Directory /var/www/abc.biz/> AllowOverride All` for your specific host directory, where your web site is placed.
Also you should check  .htaccess files placed in your /var/www/abc.biz directory to be correctly writen, because when you enable .htaccess files to override global apache settings wrong .htaccess file causes such error.

Comment: In ubuntu 13.10 it's /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf !

Comment: Yes, because Ubuntu 13.10 is using Apache 2.4. As well as 000-default having been renamed to 000-default.conf, you'll also find that the <Directory /> settings are no longer there. Now they all seem to be in /etc/apache2/apache.conf

Comment: CRITICAL: For Apache 2.4, you must NOT use the `Order allow,deny` or `allow from all` lines (just remove them).  Instead, use `Require all granted` (from http://stackoverflow.com/a/18407768/368896).