# rewrite_mod is enabled but .htaccess is not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am using apache 2.2 in ubuntu 12.04 in Amazon EC2.
I enabled mod_rewrite using

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

and able to see with

```
apache2ctl -M
```

now I wrote the .htaccess code as following and is not working

```
# Redirect everything in this directory to "good.html"



    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule .* good.html
```

Here is my contents of /etc/apache2/sites-available/default
http://pastebin.com/urNfmqan

when I add 
`LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so` to the httpd.conf I get this
`waiting [Thu Apr 11 18:44:12 2013] [warn] module rewrite_module is already loaded, skipping` and htaccess is not working even then ( I presume in apache2.2 we don't edit httpd.conf to enable rewrite_mod but as per anubhava comments I modified the question)

Comment: Where is the htaccess file and what URL are you trying to access?

Comment: @JonLin .htaccess is in /var/www/bare_test and I am accesssing http://dhilcare.com/bare_test/ which should should me good.html

Comment: Most likely you don't have .htaccess enabled in your `httpd.conf`

Comment: Try putting some garbage text in your .htaccess and see if you get 500 (Internal Server Error) or not.

Comment: I am not getting 500( error) but I am able to see index page

Comment: If you're not getting 500 then it means your .htaccess is not enabled. Pls enable it and you are all set :)

Comment: when I add `LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so` to the httpd.conf I get this `waiting [Thu Apr 11 18:44:12 2013] [warn] module rewrite_module is already loaded, skipping` and htaccess is not working

Comment: Enabling mod_rewrite is different from enabling .htaccess.

Comment: @anubhava Sorry, then how do I enable .htaccess ?

Comment: Change `AllowOverride None` to `AllowOverride All` for for your DOCUMENT_ROOT's `<Directory ...` entry.

Comment: I did it, but still when I am accessing dhilcare.com/bare_test/ I am seeing contents of index.html and not good.html

Comment: @Madhu13: Check this answer for more details on how to do this in Ubuntu 12.04: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064005/enable-htaccess-error-on-ubuntu-12-04-with-apache2

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28057/discussion-between-madhu13-and-anubhava)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /good.html [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

You should change the Base and the second element in the rewrite rule to whatever your directory is if it's not root.

Comment: Try some of the suggestions given by @anubhava to first determine whether your .htaccess is working at all.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn When I try to access dhilcare.com/bare_test I am going to index.html and not good.html

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you will have a rewrite loop. Apache rewrite doesn't run the rules once, but once for every time a path is requested. So on first load it rewrites `.*` to `good.html`. Then it makes an internal request for `good.html` and re-processes the rules again, rewriting again and makes another internal request to infinity. Revent's answer tries to solve this by checking if the file exists. You get `index.html` in his rules because `index.html` exists. If you removed `index.html` the file wouldn't exist, the rewrite condition would match and the rule would rewrite to `good.html`. When re-processing the rules, the file exists, the condition fails and redirect stops after that.

To fix, you can add the `[L]` flag after your rewrite rule to tell apache to stop processing rules after this one runs which should stop the loop. If that doesn't help, you can add a `rewriteCond` to check that the `request_filename` is not `good.html` causing the rule to fail after redirect.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @Jonathan Kuhn, just for clarification - does the L flag in my RewriteRule not do what you're describing?

Comment: @Revent It does, but when loading your htaccess, he is getting index.html because the file exists. I believe he is trying to load a directory and apache is trying to load the index page. The `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` finds the index page (that rule says if file doesn't exist continue processing) and so the rule never runs. So like I said, remove index.html and your conds/rules should work. You could also remove the two rewriteConds and it should work also.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Learn something new every day... :)